# Background worker, and cross thread issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a Winforms application which is working fine.. using a BackgroundWorkerThread to manage GUI usability during processing of serial data to a device.

It's working fine.

Now, I am adding a new method, and copying what I did in other forms. But I am getting a cross thread exception.

I declare my BWT like this:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += DownloadGpsDataFromDevice;
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I then have a method delared like this, which does the background work:

```
private void DownloadGpsDataFromDevice(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _performScreenUpdate = true;
    tsStatus.Text = "Downloading GPS Data...";
    Invalidate();
    Refresh();


    Common.WriteLog("Extracting raw GPS data. Sending LL.");

    ReplyString raw = DeviceServices.ExecuteCommand("$LL");
```

The DeviceServices.ExecuteCommand("$LL"); is the bit that does the work, but I am getting the exception on the previous line, where I log to a text file. Now, that makes you worry - writing to a file. However, I have done this thousands of times in another BWT.

I made the writing thread safe. Here this my Common.WriteLog method:

```
public static void WriteLog(string input)
{
    lock (_lockObject)
    {
        WriteLogThreadSafe(input);
    }
}

private static void WriteLogThreadSafe(string input)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(LogFilePath);
    StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(LogFilePath + @"\" + LogFileName);
    try
    {
        w.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", DateTime.Now, input));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Error writing to log file!");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Tried to write: [" + input + "]");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Failed with error: [" + e.Message + "]");
    }
    finally
    {
        w.Close();
    }

}
```

This have been working for ages. I don't believe the error is there. I think I am just missing something on the call maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change UI elements from BackgroundWorker thread. You'll have to marshall back to UI thread by calling `Invoke()`.

Try this

```
private void DownloadGpsDataFromDevice(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _performScreenUpdate = true;
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
             tsStatus.Text = "Downloading GPS Data...";
             Invalidate();
             Refresh();
     });
     ...
```

Comment: Those lines seem to work OK... or am I getting a false error? It crashes on Common.WriteLog("Extracting raw GPS data. Sending LL.");

Comment: Wait... you're right, it seems! The app crashed on the LogLine, but when I comment out those lines you mention... it works. Strange that it crashes on the log line though. Thanks!

Comment: @cdotlister  `WriteLog()` seems okay to me and should not be causing cross-thread exception. I'm not sure in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are updating UI elements from non-UI thread:

Those lines should not be inside of `DownloadGpsDataFromDevice`

```
tsStatus.Text = "Downloading GPS Data...";
Invalidate();
Refresh();
```

To take advantage of `BackgroundWorker` run method `bw.ReportProgress(0);`. Update UI in `ProgressChanged` handler, which was specifically designed for this purpose.

```
void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ProgressPercentage = 0)
    {
        tsStatus.Text = "Downloading GPS Data...";
        Invalidate();
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Those lines seem to work OK... or am I getting a false error? It crashes on  Common.WriteLog("Extracting raw GPS data. Sending LL.");

Comment: Wait... you're right, it seems! The app crashed on the LogLine, but when I comment out those lines you mention... it works. Strange that it crashes on the log line though. Thanks!

Comment: @cdotlister - You don't need to use if you don't use `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` events. Those two events are the whole point of the `BackgroundWorker`. Those events are always triggered in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Some instances can't or should not be accessed by multiple threads. You have two options to protect your data from cross thread exceptions.

You can lock your object when you access it from multiple threads with a lock:

object locker = new object();

SomeObject MyObject = new SomeObject();

```
private void FromMultipleThread()
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        MyObject = OtherObject;
    }
}
```

Your second option is to lock your thread with a ManualResetEvent. It is very simple, you only have to call WaitOne() from you ManualResetEvent to lock your thread while an other thread access your "cross threaded" Object.

In your case, you would want to change your UI from the reportProgress of your backgroundWorker. The reportProgress will come back to the initial thread, then you can modify your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the right line?  I don't think you should be able to update the ui in your worker.  Try commenting out the gui update and clean and build your solution to see if the logging is really the problem.  To update the ui, set WorkerReportsProgress and create an event handler for that to update the ui and report progress in the worker.